# not getting output of java program

Tags: java

```
package com.gautam.notepad;

import javax.swing.*;    

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        panel1 p =new panel1();  // This is the panel1 class object
        new App("NOTEPAD",p);    // i'm trying to pass panel1 object



    }
}


class App extends JFrame {

    public App(String title,panel1 panel)
    {
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setSize(800, 640);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.add(panel);
        this.setResizable(false);
    }
}

class panel1 extends JPanel{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());



    }
}
```

it works fine but in the paintcomponent method it is g.fillRect() method 
is not working it is not painting the whole screen only small rectangle is painted in the middle of the screen.what is the problem in this code

Comment: Well you're missing a call to super.paintComponent(g), but the code is "fine". Its painting a rectangle the size of the JPanel. If you want the rectangle to be bigger, then you may need to investigate why your JPanel is not as big as you want it to be. Try commenting out that setLayout() line so the JFrame will still have its default BorderLayout, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, that will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem on line `this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());`, just remove it and it will work. By default it will use BorderLayout which is what you need.

Comment: Great :) You can also remove it since BorderLayout is used by default

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
import javax.swing.*;    
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class NotePad {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    App app = new App("NOTEPAD");  
    app.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);


}
}


class App extends JFrame {

public App(String title)
{
    this.setTitle(title);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setSize(800, 640);
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    //this.add(panel);
    this.setResizable(false);
}
}
```

Comment: I doesn't want to display it in this way i want to draw a panel and in the panel void paint component method i like to paint the whole screen by the green colour by using the g.fillrect method

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with your selected Layout.Have a look at this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#flow to see the different layouts and how to use them.

If you change `this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());` to `this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());` for instance, it should work

Comment: Please mark your question as answered if one of the suggested answers worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Ok `Flowlayout()` gets it's own size and it happens that that small size is what you're getting from the `flowlayout()`, if you want to be still able to use the `Flowlayout()` and control the dimensions of your green Rectangle than i suggest using the `setPreferredSize()` method on your panel which will eliminate this problem and will keep your `FlowLayout` too.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        panel1 p =new panel1();  // This is the panel1 class object
        Dimension size= new Dimension(800, 640);//here you can add the size you want 
        p.setPreferredSize(size);
        new App("NOTEPAD",p);    // i'm trying to pass panel1 object



    }
```